# Ubuntu Terminal Not Accepting Password Input

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, arm

I have installed Ubuntu on MacOS using UTM, this is the ARM version on an M1 Mac running in virtualisation.

I have rebooted after installing the program, the terminal accepts username input but not password input -I am certain the password is correct.

[image: linux terminal: username field, empty]

I have restarted the VM and this behaviour persists. I would like to understand the reason for it and how to resolve it.

[Edit] now resolved

Comment: What do you mean by "not accepting password input"? There are no symbols shown in Terminal when entering a password -- it's done blind.  Do you see a message that *the password is  wrong*?

Comment: I just test one Ubuntu machine and the password is dots so you can see progress. The other Ubuntu machines are the same. Try spinning up a test Ubuntu machine and see if it is different or the same

Comment: @emmessenn: How did you resolve it? I’m also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Tharun The author did not respond to comments, even when he or she was active; didn't share the solution; has been inactive for months. Obviously the author was here only to leach help, not to participate. It's unlikely your comment will be answered. IMO in these circumstances it's totally justified for you to [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). Make it better than this question (e.g. "not accepting input" is vague), respond to future comments, publish your own answer in case you solve it by yourself. Then this unfortunate question will be closed and yours will stay.